# Excel "this action won't work on multiple selections" after adding sheet

Tags: excel, vba

here's my issue, I created a vba code that opens a file and copies the content into a new worksheet that i add to the current workbook.

However, when i try to read the data, the code always crashes and i get the message "this action won't work on multiple selections".

From what i googled (not a vba expert here) the issue comes from selection with different sizes therefore do you think the issue could come from somewhere else ?

I've added some "debug.print" to check (the ones in comment below) and only the "Before" is read. The issue comes from the line sh.Name = "Output" according to the debbugger. But i don't really see why it could come from here... Any ideas ?

```
dim sh as Worksheet

' Debug.Print "Before"
sh.Name = "Output"
' Debug.Print "Middle"
set sh = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
' Debug.Print "After"
```

Comment: Move `sh.Name = "Output"` to after you create the new sheet.

Comment: Doesn't work, already tried but the issue moves to the first line

Comment: Please show a full [mcve] not just some lines of code. The code above cannot work for one obvious reason: After `dim sh` the variable `sh` is nothing, and nothing has no `sh.Name`. Please [edit] and show a proper example with the exact error message and on which line of code you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the workbook, from office doc:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet =activeWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
```

Comment: Nope, still get the same message with the multiple section

Comment: can you post your full code?